# Unable to locate package ros-noetic-bfl

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done `sudo apt(-get) update` by times.

And most of other packages of `ros-noetic` have been normally installed.

Has `ros-noetic-bfl` been renamed in noetic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404302/unable-to-locate-package-ros-noetic-bfl/) by [Sinogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/111638/sinogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/bfl) says the Bayesian Filter Library is orphaned.

You can try compiling the older ros package source link on the wiki page, or you can install it as a regular system library from apt using package name `liborocos-bfl-dev`.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sinogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/111638/sinogi/) on 2022-07-28**:
Many thanks! ( ﾟ∀。)